# SVM - non separable case/soft margin, where are the support vectors

Tags: machine-learning, svm

[image]

My Question is - in the inseparable case(where we add slack variables)
$\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{w}{\text{minimize}}
& & \ ||w||^2 + C \sum_{1}^{m} \epsilon_i\\
& \text{subject to}
& & y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)} +b) \geq 1 - \epsilon_i, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
& & \epsilon_i \geq 0, \; i = 1, \ldots, m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}$

I selected 2 vectors in the image above, which one of them is misclassified and the other is in the wrong side of the margin.
My question is, are they support vectors?
Or the rule for support vectors is that they lie on the margin, ie $|wx-b|=1$?

Comment: They are both support vectors, together with the points that are on the margin.  For the points on the margin the lagrange multiplier $\alpha$ will be strictly smaller than C, for the points that you pointed to the lagrange multiplier will be equal to C.

Comment: So please let me know if I am right about the following properties:
$ \epsilon_i>0 \iff a_i =C $ 
And $ 0< \epsilon_i \le \frac{b}{||w||} $ is a margin violation
And $ \epsilon_i > \frac{b}{||w||} $ is a misclassification

Comment: $\epsilon_i > 0 \Rightarrow \alpha_i = C$ (but not the other way around, a point can be just on the margin and still have 0 error). $0 < \epsilon_i < 1$ is a margin violation. $\epsilon_i \geq 1$ is generally taken to be a misclassification (of course when $\epsilon_i = 1$ it depends on whether one takes the 0 value to be +1 or -1).